# Sometimes File.exists() returns false for system ringtone

Tags: android, ringtone

I have received log from the user about music not always playing. Strangely, cause seems to be missing system ringtone file.

Path to file is `/system/media/audio/alarms/Alarm_Classic.ogg`

I load it to MediaPlay with:

```
mp.setDataSource(context, Uri.parse(Uri.encode(fileInfo)));
mp.prepareAsync();
```

This causes `MediaPlayer's` onError(1, -2147483648). For logging purposes after that I am checking if file exists by:

```
File file = new File(fileInfo);
if (!file.exists()) {
   //log
}
```

And the sent log states, that the file was actually missing. Pretty strange, considering that it was playing fine for few previous days and user said he didn't do anything with the file.

Phone is Galaxy Nexus with Android 4.2.2.

Any ideas what may be causing described behaviour? Looks like random problem with reading permissions - is that maybe a known bug?

Comment: It's likely that file - if it was ever present - was lost at some point in an upgrade, at least it does not seem to be part of stock 4.2.2